# Is it possible to use specific ICU library (.jar) in ant xslt task in DITA-OT?

Tags: java, xslt, ant, dita-ot

I am developing `DITA-OT plugin` that offers several *.jars* to be used from other `DITA-OT plug-in`.

This plugin uses `ICU library (http://site.icu-project.org/）icu4j-4_8.jar` and must support from *DITA-OT 1.7.5* to the newest *DITA-OT 2.2.1*.
However, I know that *DITA-OT* bundles **ICU library in DITA-OT/lib** directory. The newest version seems to be `icu4j-54.1.jar`.

My problem is this **ICU library**. When my plugin is used by xslt task in other plugin, I explicitly specified `icu4j-4_8.jar` as **xslt/@classpathref**. But, the output result seems that *xslt task* uses *ICU library from DITA-OT/lib* directory because of pre-process or other previous steps has already used it.

Are there any ways to **force ant xslt task to use specific ICU .jar** file specified by *xslt/@classpathref*?

Comment: Specify the required jar file in the beginning of your `classpath` and then append the rest.

Comment: Yes, it will be the most certain solution specifying my favorite ICU .jar file into CLASSPATH at the beginning of DITA-OT (startcmd.bat or startcmd.sh). However it is also the reason why I posted this question.
As my plugin is used in various DITA-OT versions by user, I cannot oblige them to rewrite startcmd.bat or startcmd.sh to use specific ICU .jar file.

Comment: Would you please post the script where the class path is set by editing the question?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. The build file(s) exist in the following GitHub repository. 
[https://github.com/AntennaHouse/pdf5-ml](https://github.com/AntennaHouse/pdf5-ml)
This is plugin uses my plugin that uses ICU library.
The relevant lines are:
Defining path for icu4j-4_8.jar: build.xml. line 37, 
Adding classpathref to xslt task: build_transform.xml line 105